# AJAX Load doesn't work with script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to create a website where HTML-code gets loaded into a div when document is done loading. Though, the hover function doesn't work with AJAX-load. Please help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sidebar').load('sidebar-main.php');

    $("#sidebar .section").hover(function() {
            $('#sidebar .section .left-mark').show();
        },function(){
            $('#sidebar .section .left-mark').hide();
        });
});
```

The "sidebar-main.php" file:

```
<div class='section' onclick='header()'><div class='left-mark'></div></div>
```

The sidebar in the main PHP-file:

```
<div id='sidebar'></div>
```

Comment: have you tried using `on` handler for ajax like `$("#sidebar .section").on('hover',function(){ ...});`

Comment: Did not work :(

Comment: `load()` has a callback function when the load has completed. This means, I think, it works asynchronous. So I advice to use the callback function. See: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On newly created elements (refer to **.load()**), you need to delegate the event handler to your **#sidebar** ancestor.

Hence, change this:

```
$("#sidebar .section").hover(function() {
    $('#sidebar .section .left-mark').show();
},function(){
    $('#sidebar .section .left-mark').hide();
});
```

to:

```
$("#sidebar").on('mouseenter', '.section', function() {
    $('#sidebar .section .left-mark').show();
}).on('mouseleave', '.section',function(){
    $('#sidebar .section .left-mark').hide();
});
```

A demo:

```js
//
// instead on next line, for testing I added the next one
//
//$('#sidebar').load('1.php');
$('#sidebar').append("<div class='section' onclick='header()'>aa<div class='left-mark'>bb</div></div>");

$("#sidebar").on('mouseenter', '.section', function() {
    $('#sidebar .section .left-mark').show();
}).on('mouseleave', '.section',function(){
    $('#sidebar .section .left-mark').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id='sidebar'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#sidebar').load('sidebar-main.php', bindHoverEvent);
function bindHoverEvent() {
    $("#sidebar .section").hover(function() {
       $('#sidebar .section .left-mark').show();
    }, function(){
        $('#sidebar .section .left-mark').hide();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the reason this isn't working is because `.load()` is asynchronous, meaning the code following the `.load()` call will execute before the content is loaded. There's two solutions here:

1. Put your `hover` call in the callback handler like this:

   ```
   $('#sidebar').load('sidebar-main.php', function() {
        $("#sidebar .section").hover(function() {
           $('#sidebar .section .left-mark').show();
        },function(){
           $('#sidebar .section .left-mark').hide();
       });
   });
   ```
2. Attach the `hover` listener to the `body` tag but only do a call when `#sidebar .section` is the element hovered. Note that `hover` is shorthand for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. Like this:

   ```
   $('body').on('mouseenter', '#sidebar .section', function() {
        $('#sidebar .section .left-mark').show();
   }).on('mouseleave', '#sidebar .section', function() {
        $('#sidebar .section .left-mark').hide();
   });
   ```

In the second solution you don't have to worry about the load being asynchronous because the listener is already attached to the body.